# How to find $\max_{0\le{s}\le{1}}\int_{0}^{1}{|\ln|s-t||}dt$

Tags: real-analysis

How to find $$\max_{0\le{s}\le{1}}\int_{0}^{1}{|\ln|s-t||}dt$$

Since $$\int_{0}^{1}{|\ln|s-t||}dt=-\int_{0}^{s}{\ln(s-t)}dt-\int_{s}^{1}{\ln(t-s)}dt$$
I tried to caculate 
$$\int_{0}^{s}{\ln(s-t)}dt=t\ln(s-t)|_{0}^{s}-\int_{0}^{s}{\frac{t}{s-t}}dt$$
I am confused about the first part on the right. It seems to be $s\ln{(s-s)}$ which has no means.
I can't find a similar example with detailed explanation. Best regards!

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/272831) After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I'm sorry for my carelessness. I fixed the question.

Comment: The first line seems wrong.

Comment: Note that your edit has removed my edit from the post. As is, your post has no clear question. If one were to disregard the title, it would seem as though you are asking how to evaluate the integral or what your mistake was. Even if this were the case, I find this question grounds to facing closure as "unclear".

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I am sorry for misunderstanding you. I return the question to your edition. And I will be careful next time.

Comment: Thanks $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your integration by parts does not work as the right-hand side of the second equation is of the form $\infty - \infty$ (ignoring a sign mistake you made for the last integral). This can be avoided as follows:

  \begin{align*}
  -\int_{0}^{s} \log(s - t) \, dt
  &= \left[ (s - t)\log (s-t) \right]_{t=0}^{t=s} - \int_{0}^{s} (-1) \, dt \\
  &= s - s \log s.
  \end{align*}

  Here we utilized the fact that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x \log x = 0$.
- Similar computation tells that

  \begin{align*}
  -\int_{s}^{1} \log(t - s) \, dt
  &= \left[ (s - t) \log(t - s) \right]_{t=s}^{t=1} - \int_{s}^{1} (-1) \, dt \\
  &= (1-s) - (1-s)\log(1-s).
  \end{align*}
- Combining two, we obtain

  $$ \int_{0}^{1} \left| \log \left|s - t\right| \right| \, dt = 1 - s\log s - (1-s)\log(1-s). $$

  This is enough to give an answer to your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. I know the question is quite basic, but I get strucked. You do help me a lot. Thanks again.